# Dynamically change range of FormatCondition

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, conditional-formatting

I have added a Format Condition on a range with some formatting using the below code.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition formatConditionObj = null;

formatConditionObj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.FormatCondition)myRange
    .FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, 
    Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

formatConditionObj.Interior.ColorIndex = 5;
```

Now my range changes `dynamically`.I want that using the same FormatCondition object i just change the range where this formats are applied. For e.g at the first instance it might be just `"$A$1"` later it might be `"$A$2,$D$5"` or `"$A$3:$A$20"`.

This can be done using excel directly. Contitional Formatting -> Manage Rules -> Applies To(Edit this). How can be this acheived using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. I find putting the "using" line below at the top saves a good deal of effort.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

<...>

        formatConditionObj = (FormatCondition)myRange.FormatConditions
            .Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, 
            Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        formatConditionObj.Interior.ColorIndex = 5;

        Range myNewRange = ws.Range["a10:a15"];
        formatConditionObj.ModifyAppliesToRange(myNewRange);

 <...>
```

Comment: using ModifyAppliesToRange gives an exception when trying to access the formula(Formula1) of formatConditionObj after applying myNewRange on formatConditionObj. Why is this behaviour?

Comment: You might like to ask that as a new question with some additional detail, because I am nit quite sure what you mean.

Comment: i have raised a new question for the same kindly refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048627/modifyappliestorange-of-formatcondition-causes-its-formula-to-throw-exception